# How should I properly capture submitted form values with Contact Form 7 (wp)?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've recently done a GTM set up to track checkboxes for a WordPress Contact Form with contact form 7. I've obviously read [this article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/) from from Simo but to be honest I didn't really understand it so here is what I've finally done :

A custom Javascript :

```
function checkbox_selector() {var array = ["group-963","group-964","group-965"];
    if ( document.getElementById(array[0]).style.display == "block" ) { return "Checkbox#1" }
    else if ( document.getElementById(array[1]).style.display == "block" ) { return "Checkbox#2" }
    else if ( document.getElementById(array[2]).style.display == "block" ) { return "Checkbox#3" }
    else { return "unchecked" }
}
```

I used this custom Javascript to fill the event action tracking parameters in an event tag. The tag itself was fired on a simple form submission trigger.

Reading my custom Javascript you will understand that I didn't found any other solution than playing with display style of some elements.

Is there any way I could have done this job better ?

Comment: Can't you just attach an on handler on the checkboxes class and read the inputs value or checked attribute? In your current approach you aren't flexible if there are other checkbox IDs created in the future.

Comment: hi @MarnixHarderwijk you are totally right, my approach isn't flexible at all. however I didn't had access to the wordpress back-office. however what did you mean exactly when you say "attach an on handler on the checkboxes class" ?

Comment: For instance the input checkboxes would have a class="checkbox", right? If so you should attach an on click handler, read if the checkbox is set or not and sent it to GTM with your push function.

Comment: ha yep ok got it. Probably a simpler and better solution ! you can post it as an answer ! thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created an example for you to play around with:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
 var $this = $(this);
  
  var checkVal = $(this).is(':checked');
  var checkName = $(this).attr('name');
  
  // do your push to GTM here
  alert(checkName + ', ' + checkVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="tony" value="tony" />
<input type="checkbox" name="pepper" value="pepper" />
```

The fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrpharderwijk/56ef50og/1/